# Apply Excel formula to every nth cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I was wondering if there is a worksheet function to apply the same set of mathematical transformations involving three separate cells, but every 5th row down. An example of this in Excel would be, in a new column, say column `I`:

- `H5 -(C5 * H8)` followed by
- `H10 -(C10 * H13)` in the next cell down, then
- `H15 -(C15 * H18)` and so on

Those (`H` and `C`) are the only two columns I am wanting to apply this exact formula to, but for hundreds of iterations down the spreadsheet. Those are just the first three samples. Imagine that formula extending all the way up through `H500 - (C500 * H503)`, for instance. I would like to just apply this formula to a few iterations and then drag-to-fill the rest of the column, but this does not work.

Comment: Please be clearer about what you want.  Do you want the formulas you show in cells `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, …, cells `A5`, `A10`, `A15`, …, or cells `P1`, `Q1`, `R1`, …?  What do you mean by “across rows and columns”? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Will do, sorry about that.

Comment: Did that edit help to clarify my question enough?

Answer (score 2):

Enter `=H5 -(C5 * H8)` in cell `I5`. 
Leave cells `I1:I4` blank. 
Select cells `I1:I5` and drag/fill down as far as you need.

[image: the process of setting it up]

Result:

[image: the resulting spreadsheet]

Comment: Working properly +10 ,, but I do believe that VBA macro should be best suitable (even though is not been demanded) since OP has huge range to copy all this☺

Answer (score 1):

In cell I1:

```
=INDEX(H:H,ROW()*5)-(INDEX(C:C,ROW()*5) * INDEX(H:H,(ROW()*5)+3))
```

Then copy down. If you start from a cell below I1 (eg I2 or I5) you will need to adjust the formulas to account for the offset eg (ROW()-1)*5